# Why don't such ions form if half-filled or full-filled configurations are considered stable?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

We all know atoms want to stabilize by having an octet or duplet configuration. But if you see nitrogen which has an electron configuration of $\ce{2p^3}$. It has half filled p orbital, so it is technically stable, isn't it? Then why don't elements like oxygen form a monovalent oxygen ion?

By similar logic, sodium has $\ce{3s^1}$ configuration which should also be stable because it has a half filed orbital. But sodium is reactive as we know.

Can you please point out the flaw in my argument?

Comment: *Nitrogen which has am electron configuration of 2p3. It has half filled p orbital, so it is technically stable right?* No, a N atom is not stable in that two such atoms will form a molecule $\ce{N2}$.

Comment: Stability is relative. A half-filled orbital configuration is more stable than usual, but not as stable as an octet, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As also pointed out in the comments, there is no such thing as absolute stability. One species is stable *only with respect to* another species.

You may have come across the fact - that half-filled configurations are "stable" - while studying ionization enthalpy/electron gain enthalpy, or the electronic configuration of $\ce{3d}$ elements. Pay careful attention: the half-filled configuration is "stable", but only with respect to the neighbouring configurations. That is to say, the $\ce{2p^3}$ configuration is much stable than $\ce{2p^4}$ or $\ce{2p^2}$. Yet, $\ce{2p^3}$ is still very less stable than $\ce{2p^6}$. This is why, in nature, nitrogen prefers to exist in diatomic molecules, so as to complete its octet.

Now for the fully-filled $\ce{3s^2}$ configuration (sodium anion, aka "sodide"): again, note that the sodium cation is way more stable than the sodium anion, as the former has a fully filled octet, while the latter doesn't. (Sodide has indeed been formed, but by using special techniques only. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide)).

Also see: [Why are atoms with eight electrons in the outer shell extremely stable?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/1196) and [Why do atoms "want" to have a full outer shell?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16922/why-do-atoms-want-to-have-a-full-outer-shell)

Comment: Well, I think there may be need to do a bit of debunking of debunking. Inherent instability is quite a thing and you seem to be rather talking about reactivity.

Comment: @Mithoron Could you please elaborate a bit more on your statement: " Inherent instability is quite a thing"?

Comment: If something is inherently unstable, it breaks down by itself.