# Is it okay for a sulfite ion to have 10 electrons around the sulfur?

Tags: bond

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an atom have more than 8 valence electrons? If not, why is 8 the limit?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/444/can-an-atom-have-more-than-8-valence-electrons-if-not-why-is-8-the-limit)

I was watching this youtube clip ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XY1XLgHUAIQ ) in which a lewis diagram was drawn for a sulfite ion.

Sulfur ends up with four bonds as well as a lone pair of electrons. This gives sulfur 10 electrons. Isn't this too many?

Comment: Hi DLA, it is a nice question. It has been asked already, in a somewhat more generic manner, so I am closing yours as a duplicate. The short answer is: yes, it is possible! This behavior of elements from the third period and lower is called [**hypervalence**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervalent_molecule).