Why exactly the stability of peroxides increase on going down the group
Why the stability of peroxides and superoxides increase down the group 1 and whereas the stability of oxides decrease down the group.
The reason for one of them in my textbook is given as lattice energy, but then what about the other?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24762/why-does-potassium-form-peroxides-but-sodium-does-not
