# Why does AsH5 not exist?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, hybridization

Why does $\ce{AsH5}$ not exist? Is it because the s-orbital of H doesn't and can't overlap with the d-orbital of As after As makes $\rm sp^{3}d$ hybridization?Theoretically the bond can occur because we can make $\rm sp^3d^2$ hybridization for As to give rise for 5 orbitals with 1 electron each and which can accept the  5 H atoms, but why is this not true in reality?

Comment: Related: [Why do compounds like SF6 and SF4 exist but SH6 and SH4 don't?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/why-do-compounds-like-sf6-and-sf4-exist-but-sh6-and-sh4-dont)

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate question.  See especially page 15 of "Ligand Coupling Reactions with Heteroatomic Compounds"  https://books.google.com/books?id=gGNvHkXpKkIC&pg=PA15&dq=ash5&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi72buEiazKAhUBy2MKHcR2D_wQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=ash5&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD You can convert your above comment into an answer.