# Why is there no non-bonding molecular orbital in the overlap between H1s and Be2s in BeH2

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

I've only recently started learning about this and I'm stating to get confused. (The orbital in the middle belongs to Be) So you have a + (+) + which gives a sigma bonding orbital and a + (-) + which gives a sigma anti-bonding orbital. Why isn't there a + (-) - which would result in a non-bonding orbital?

Comment: If you look up the MOs of the allyl cation, it's exactly the same system here, except that you're dealing with s orbitals instead of p orbitals. The nonbonding orbital has no coefficient on beryllium because the antibonding linear combination of hydrogen orbitals ($A_{1u}$) does not have an appropriate symmetry match with the beryllium 2s ($A_{1g}$). Of course, this treatment is a bit simplistic because it neglects the beryllium 2p orbitals entirely; DSVA's answer covers those nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need two sigma bonds here, and two anti-bonding ones. And there are actually two non-bonding orbitals here.

First of all: how you write it down doesn't really work, since there are p-orbitals in Be, not only s-orbitals. You need to look at them too, not only the s-orbitals. And I'm not quite sure if you did, but don't confuse Valence Bond and MO theory.

So for Valence Bond Theory:

We know this molecule is linear. Therefore we need two orbitals on the Be which can form bonds with the hydrogens and are in an 180° angle. So we do sp-hybridization and with one sp-orbital from Be and the s-orbital from hydrogen we can form a $\sigma$ and $\sigma^*$ orbital on each side. Two sigma bonds and two empty p-orbitals on Be which are non-bonding.

For MO Theory:

We construct a $\ce{H2}$ first, in this case we could write + + and + -, so we got a bonding and an antibonding orbital. Now we put our Be in the middle. And now it get's quite complicate to write down, so [here on page 10](http://www.lasalle.edu/~prushan/IC-articles/Polyatomic%20Molecular%20Orbital%20Theory.pdf) you can find the MO of $\ce{BeH2}$. You see that the bonding "$\ce{H2}$" orbital was combined with the 2s orbital of Be in an bonding and antibonding way, and the antibonding + - orbital of "$\ce{H2}$" was combined with a p-orbital in a binding and antibinding way. The two other p-orbitals aren't used and are non-bonding, since they would have equal constructive and deconstructive interaction with both "$\ce{H2}$" orbitals. In the end same result as with the valence bond theory.

Comment: I've been over what it actually looks like, but if I was to start a MO diagram is there no other way to do it other than from starting with H2.

Comment: Of course there are, you could also just "throw" all three atoms together, but it get's much harder to understand which orbitals will combine to form a new one. In case of molecules with one central atom and "ligands" around it the best way to do this is combine the ligands first

Comment: So if I was to do a MO for H2O, I'd take the same approach. Start with H2 then see how those overlap with the orbitals on the O atom.

Comment: Yes exactly. That's also described stepwise in the linked pdf starting on page 6, LGOs are the ligand group orbitals, the "H2" molecule.

Comment: @ShubhamR You'll find that this approach is pretty general. For example in one of my answers [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/why-do-compounds-like-sf6-and-sf4-exist-but-sh6-and-sh4-dont/49844#49844) you'll see that I constructed the "F6" ligand group orbitals (elsewhere you might also see the terminology symmetry-adapted linear combinations) first before deciding which sulfur AOs to overlap them with.