# Aluminium isopropoxide electronic structure

Tags: electronic-configuration, organometallic-compounds

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_isopropoxide#Structure):

> A tetrameric structure of the crystalline material was verified by NMR spectroscopy and X-ray crystallography. The species is described by the formula $\ce{Al[(μ-O-i-Pr)2Al(O-i-Pr)2]3}$. The unique central $\ce{Al}$ is octahedral, and three other $\ce{Al}$ centers adopt tetrahedral geometry. The idealised point group symmetry is $D_3$.

[image: Aluminum isopropoxide structure]

I can understand that the 3 external $\ce{Al}$ atoms can be (inaccurately?) described as assuming an ${sp^3}$ hybridization. With 4 bonds per $\ce{Al}$ atom, the valence shell is complete, following the octet rule. This too may deserve some additional attention, since $\ce{Al}$ formally has only 3 electrons available for bonding, yet here it forms 4 bonds. At least one of these is dative, I assume?

I'm less clear on the central $\ce{Al}$ atom. My initial instinct was to invoke the ${sp^3d^2}$ hybridization. But [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/49844/103633) re $\ce{SF6}$ suggests that may not be the case. There are clearly similarities to the $\ce{SF6}$ case, but surely, also some differences? After all, $\ce{Al}$ is not $\ce{S}$.

In short, **what is the electronic structure of the four $\ce{Al}$ centers?**

Comment: It might be easier to consider all of the Al atoms as Al3+ actions and all the propoxide groups as anions. Each O has three lone pairs that can interact with the metal

Comment: Yes, that's true. Each $\ce{O}$ atom has one valence electron used up in the $\ce{O-C}$ bond, and each $\ce{Al}$ donates one electron to each of 3 $\ce{O}$ atoms, completing their valence shells. The oxygens should all be equivalent, so we can probably think of all of the $\ce{O-Al}$ bonds as dative.

Comment: More accurately, the $\ce{O}$ should be *almost* equivalent. For example, some of them are bridging, while others are not.