# How can PCl₆⁻ be formed

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

So my teacher told me that PCl6- exists, But how? What I don't understand is that Phosphorus has 5 valence electrons hence a covalency of 5 but this doesn't allow for 6 fluorine atoms to bond with Phosphorus. Can someone show me the hybridisation or the technical reason and my teacher left off by saying that P can have hypervalent due to d orbitals but if electrons arent present to bond then how does this happen?

Comment: Try to search this site for similar questions, as similar topics have been asked multiple times. If googling, insert the term "site:chemistry.stackexchange.com".

Comment: [Related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/why-do-compounds-like-sf6-and-sf4-exist-but-sh6-and-sh4-dont)  for SF6 and false idea of involving of d orbitals in $\mathrm{sp^3d^2}$ hybridization.

Comment: the main doubt is on excitation P can only have an sp3d hybridization that will provide 5 hybridized orbitals then how can a sixth one appear out of nowhere?

Comment: @orthocresol is the author of the linked answer and has much better insight, ragarding what from the link is applicable and what is to be added or modified.

Comment: @Poutnik OP's name suggests he is from India, where these hypervalent hybridizations are **widely and unambiguously** taught throughout grades 11 and 12. I have recently finished my 12th, and before I joined this site I also believed this false myth. Most unfortunate - those who don't take up chemistry in higher studies never even get to know that this entire concept is flawed.

Comment: I checked JD LEE by Sudarshan Guha, it has nothing about this in it. So, seems to be a rare point.

Comment: @TRC I remember being taught that as well in 80s. // If there is some test/exam/homework question that insists on the wrong sp3d2 hybridization answer then both electrons on the 6th orbital would come from F- anion, forming 6 fully occupied sp3d2 orbitals. // BTW LiPF6 solution in dialkylcarbonate mix is the electrolyte in Li-Ion cells.

Comment: @Poutnik - Exactly. That's what we are taught. The point about lithium ion cells was a new info for me, so thanks :)