The MO diagram of sulfur hexafluoride?
Although I have seen it explained, I haven't seen a MO diagram of SF6 on this website showing LCAO - only written explanations and vague diagrams. I was wondering if anyone could share the MO diagram. I can predict some of it - such as non bonding electrons but I can't predict the bonding electrons. So can someone post the MO diagram of sulfur hexafluoride. I am asking this because I am trying to understand the MO theory on hypercoordinated molecules.

I will probably write an answer after an exam I have to take tomorrow, meanwhile, consider this piece of explanation. Beware that it relies HEAVILY on group theory: http://stemed.site/NCSU/CH437/lec8/problems_group_theory/SF6_SALC.pdf

related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/49844/4945 There is a diagram and some explanation.
