How does the molecular orbital diagram of sulfur tetrafluoride show ionic bonding
In hypervalent molecules, people often explain them with ionic bonds. There is significant ionicity in the bonding of for example molecules like sulfur tetrafluoride and sulfur hexafluoride. I wanted to see if the MO diagram shows this However, when I look at the MO diagram of sulfur tetrafluoride, I can't understand how it has ionic bonds between S and F and especially only partially ionic bonds. I can see the 3 covalent molecular orbitals, the lone pair (S 2pz) but I can't understand which MO represents the ionic bond in the molecule

Also regarding comments about not being able to see an ionic bond, if you have a sigma bond in MO hugely polarized towards an atom, it has significant ionic character and to a point of polarization, the term Ionic bond is used. And in the resonance structures of sulfur tetrafluoride, there are as termed Lewis structure ionic bonds or more accurately significantly polarized sigma bonds. But I can't see that in the MO diagram

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/49844/9961

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/185652/the-mo-diagram-of-sulfur-hexafluoride

@Mithoron First one doesn't give a direct answer to my question. 2nd one has no answer.

"Said on the Stack exchange and in many sources online" can you link your sources?

The MO diagram with explanation is available at LibreTexts.
They determine the bond order to be three. To write this as a Lewis structure, interpret $\ce{SF4}$ as  $\ce{SF3+ + F-}$ with resonance. This shows three covalent bonds (like the hydronium ion), one lone pair on sulfur and an ionic bond.

However, when I look at the MO diagram of Sulfur tetrafluoride, I can't understand how it has ionic bonds between S and F and especially only partially ionic bonds.

MO theory does not feature localized bonds or formal charges, so you can’t “see” ionic bonds, and the concept of a partial bond also does not apply directly.

I understand which Molecular orbitals are the single covalent bonds (3 sigma bonds), the top a1 nb is the S lone pair (2pz). Which Molecular orbital is the Ionic bond and Why? It doesn't explain this bit on the libretexts

If you want to interpret the MO in terms of octet rule, you have to “give back” one of the non-bonding MOs (and the electrons) to fluorine. That’s your ion. However, this is like mixed metaphors. It is better to get the complete picture in each model, and compare the overall result, rather than trying to match up elements of the models.

If I were to make NBOs of sulfur tetrafluoride, would it be 3 polar covalent bonds, and then extra lone pair delocalized across all the atoms?

@user155568 I'd like to render a guess for the NBO: 4 bonding orbitals with reduced occupation if you treat it with the symmetry it has.

@Martin I actually made a stack exchange question on this with broadened range to answer it generally to hypervalency

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/186547/what-are-the-nbos-of-sulfur-hexafluoride

@user155568 It doesn't. It can't. Resonance is a purely mathematical concept that arises from the inability of Valence Bond Theory being able to depict delocalised bonding. There is now switching between structures. If you think it is, you need to overhaul your understanding of resonance.

@Martin Two things: Firstly you mentioned 4 bonding NBOs. Why? There are only 3 sigma bonds. And secondly there is often electron deficient bonding in hypercoordinated compounds (e.g SF6 8 electron - 6 center, SF4 - 6 electron 4 center) and also resonance hybrid shows this with non-integer bond order. I am asking whether the NBOs as a result are spread over multiple atoms despite being sigma NBOs like a 3c - 2 electron bond or 4electron - 3 center bond

Maybe it’s time to move this to chat or to the new question

Please don't. This could be discussed in [chat], but I won't participate when moved to chat. I simply do not have the time to keep that alive. I am also no tutor on NBO. It's a complex procedure and it is published. At least the initial analysis. I don't know where this is all heading.
