What are the NBOs of sulfur hexafluoride
Can someone provide images or drawings of the NBOs (Natural bonding molecular orbitals) or any other type of localized molecular orbital of sulfur hexafluoride. I can't find it anywhere on google apart from 1 or 2 algorithms which I can't use. I am trying to understand a localized-VBT approach to hypercoordination and so I want to study the NBOs. I am also visually trying to understand the resonance hybrid of the Sulfur hexafluoride resonance structures.

Please define NBO. Is https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8599/how-to-visualize-natural-atomic-orbitals-from-pyscf of any help?

NBOS are Natural bonding orbitals  -  a form of localized molecular orbitals. Also no the post doesn't help. I would like specifically SF6 and either images or drawings of the NBOs

Well this basically tells you what codes can do this for you - https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/plotting-of-natural-bond-orbitals-nbos I'm afraid if you want to get the results for a specific case you will have to learn the tools of the trade and do the calculation yourself, unless you are very lucky.

Unfortunately most of it costs money and requires external downloading. I would be appreciative if someone could find them for me or an alternative by using reasoning (e.g from VBT resonance hybrid / models) or knowledge to roughly draw the NBO (or even electron density map)
